# validate the data frame header with pandas regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

In pandas data frame has email header. for that i want to validate few domain names and special characters are available i have to save into new sheet as invalid sheet.

Here is the example data frame :

```
        Name    Email               Contact No
0   siddarth  siddarth@gmail.com    4382430
1   supreet   siupreet@outlook.com  21356908
2   sreeja    sreeja@gmail.com      78940989
3   bsreddy   bsreddy@yahoo.com     43687065
4   rakshita  rakshita/hotmail.com  43685707
5    rahul     rahul\live.com         54783929
6    cahal     chahal?msdn.com       324567889
7.   karthik   karthik:gmail.com     4356589
8    rk        rk;dell.com           65784930
```

for above data frame i want to find invalid emails and particular domain names.

```
my code snippet is :

      import re
      import pandas as pd

      demo_path = 'C:\\Users\\kiran\\Desktop\\mail_id.xlsx'
      demo_read = pd.read_excel(demo_path)
      pattern = pattern = re.compile(r'^@\w+\.[a-z]{0,3}$')
      demo_read['Isemail'] = demo_read['Email'].apply(lambda x: True if pattern.match(x) else False)
```

above is not working. for that i have used below code snippet:

```
     a=demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains('@gmail.com')]
     b=demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains('@outlook.com')]
     c=demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains('?')]
     d=demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains('/')]
     e=demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r'\\')]
     d=demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r'\?')]
     f=demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains(':')]
     g=demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains(';')]
```

and one more doubt is, can we validate and display the invalid records using regex for above code snippet domains and special characters. please suggest best method for that also.

```
  output should be like this:

            Name    Email               Contact No
   0    siddarth  siddarth@gmail.com    4382430
   1    supreet   siupreet@outlook.com  21356908
   2    sreeja    sreeja@gmail.com      78940989
   4   rakshita  rakshita/hotmail.com   43685707
   5    rahul     rahul\live.com         54783929
   6    cahal     chahal?msdn.com       324567889
   7   karthik   karthik:gmail.com     4356589
   8    rk        rk;dell.com           65784930
```

Comment: See my latest update, it get's your ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the last one that doesn't work:

```
 demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r'\\')]
```

You can try this:

```
demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])""")
```

or

```
demo_read['Email'][demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])""")]
```

or

```
demo_read['Email'][~demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])""")]
```

For the question mark one, try this:

```
demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r"\?")]
```

This will not match gmail or outlook.com:

```
demo_read[demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r"(?:(?!.*gmail.com)(?!.*outlook.com)[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])")]
```

output:

```
      Name              Email  Contact No
3  bsreddy  bsreddy@yahoo.com    43687065
```

For the output your looking for, do the inverse:

```
demo_read[~demo_read['Email'].str.contains(r"(?:(?!.*gmail.com)(?!.*outlook.com)[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])")]
```

output:

```
       Name                 Email  Contact No
0  siddarth    siddarth@gmail.com     4382430
1    supree  siupreet@outlook.com    21356908
2    sreeja      sreeja@gmail.com    78940989
4  rakshita  rakshita/hotmail.com    43685707
5     rahul        rahul\live.com    54783929
6     cahal       chahal?msdn.com   324567889
7   karthik     karthik:gmail.com     4356589
8        rk           rk;dell.com    65784930
```

Comment: can you provide the regex for that cases.
i solved that issue.thanks for your help.

Comment: @user98 updated with a general email validator from emailregex.com

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.let you know the weather it's working or not .

demo_read.loc[demo_read['Email'].str.contains("?")]            this is not working how to change this one as a work.

Comment: i updated at the end with the question one mark, i tested it and it should work

Comment: regex are not working. can you remodify for below cases:

[@gmail.com  @outlook.com  \   /  :  ;  ?]  these cases are found  will be displayed invalid records .    you helped me a lot for that thanks.

Comment: @user98 Try the last line i added, i t shouldn't match gmail or outlook.com. Please give me a checkmark if this works :-)

Comment: @user98, just edited again. Add more data if you need, but that should work, i just tested it

Comment: can i add that regex along with  these cases mentioned in bracket  [/,  \ ,  :  ,  ; ,  ?]

Comment: whatever you written that is working. i need also special characters mentioned above comment bracket.

Comment: @user98 It should be getting those, can you put the output your getting into the question so i can look at it further?

Comment: I added my required output.

Comment: @user98 try my latest update, it is the inverse of matching, which should get those

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203719/discussion-between-user-98-and-oppressionslayer).

Comment: It's the regex from https://emailregex.com/ they have an explanation chart on it. I modified it to exclude the matches you wanted. It's free to use. Did i get your answer right, would you be able to give me a green checkmark?